# How to handle nulls in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, null

I have user registration form. It has field Date of birth. It is not compulsory in database also not on UI. But while create when i am goiing to assign it to objects property, i have to convert it in to date format. But if i have not selected it, it will become null in the FormCollection object. like

User.DOB=Convert.ToDateTime(collection["DOB"]);

Now issue is if it collection["DOB"]is null then it throws exception. I can not assign default value here. So how can i handle this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably be better off using `DateTime.TryParse` for this.

This way you can check whether you're working with a valid date or not.

```
DateTime dateOfBirth;

bool isValidDateOfBirth = DateTime.TryParse(collection["DOB"], out dateOfBirth);

if(isValidDateOfBirth)
{
 // do stuff
}
else
{
 // do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: Or, why bother creating the bool when you could just check the direct output of the TryParse - `if(DateTime.TryParse...)`.

Comment: You can do that also. I included the bool here to make it explicitly clear to the OP what's going on. I don't know their skill level so I find this aproach (being a bit more expansive) to be quite useful.

Comment: I agree, but what if collection have null value, so what action have to take ?generally what developers does, if there is no defaults, and date is mandatory in DB?

Comment: If you're collecting data from a form that is required, both client side and server side validation need to be performed. There are many ways you can do this. Here's one of those ways: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx